# `Ctrl+Del` to delete following whitespaces (like in VS201X)

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS2017 when use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to delete a word, it will auto delete any following whitespaces.

Is it available to config VSC to working same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any built-in setting to do that.  You would either have to just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> **twice**

or set up a macro to run that command twice.

Using the [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) macro extension, puth is into settings.json:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.deleteWordAndWhieSpaceRight",
      "sequence": [
        "deleteWordRight",
        "deleteWordRight",
      ]
    }
]
```

and in keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+delete",
  "command": "-deleteWordRight",
  "when": "textInputFocus && !editorReadonly"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+delete",
  "command": "multiCommand.deleteWordAndWhieSpaceRight",
  "when": "textInputFocus && !editorReadonly"
},
```

[image: Delete word and whitespace right demo]